# free vector space of the product space

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Suppose that $V_1, V_2$ are two real vector spaces. Consider the free vector space $\mathscr{F}(V_1 \times V_2)$ which consists of finite linear combinations of elements of $V_1 \times V_2$. How is it different from the product vector space $V_1 \times V_2$ itself?

I think they should be the same, but in Lee's Introduction to Smooth manifolds, he considers the free vector space instead of the vector space itself. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are very different. Are you aware of what the free vector space on a set $X$ is? It is a vector space $\mathscr F(X)$ with $X$ as a basis. In particular, if you choose to be $X$ to be equal to be a real vector space $V$, then $\mathscr F(V)$ is a real vector space which has $V$ as a basis. So if, for example, $V=\Bbb R$, then $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space, but $\mathscr F(V)$ is a vector space with dimension of cardinality $\Bbb R$, and $\mathscr F(V)$ is indeed very different to $V$.

To say it in a different way, $\mathscr F(V)$ is all "formal combinations" of elements of $V$. The typical addition and scalar multiplation from $V$ doesn't apply here. So in particular, in $\mathscr F(V\times V')$, the elements $(v,0)+(0,v')$ and $(v,v')$ are different elements, even though they are the same as elements of $V\times V'$.